# NullPointerException while setting objects to an array of null

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I'm getting a NullPointerException and after doing research I can't figure out why. 
The error message reads:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at TextDecoder.readMessagesFromFile(TextDecoder.java:32)
    at TextDecoder.main(TextDecoder.java:54)
```

I've commented next to lines 54 and 32.

This is my constructor (all of these methods come from the same class):

```
  public TextDecoder() {
        messages = new TextMessage[10];
        msgCount = 0;
      }
```

My Main method is the following (I included class declaration):

```
public class TextDecoder {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    if (args.length != 1) {
      System.out.println("There is an incorrect amount of command-line arguments. Command-line Argument length: " + args.length);
      System.exit(1);
    } 
    File msgFile = new File(args[0]);
    if (msgFile == null) {
      System.out.println("File not found.");
      System.exit(1);
    }
    readMessagesFromFile(msgFile); // Line 32
}
}
```

My readMessagesFromFile is the following:

```
public static void readMessagesFromFile(File inputMsgFile) throws Exception {

Scanner input = new Scanner(inputMsgFile);

 while (input.hasNextLine()) {

   /* Some code here */
// Recipient and keyPresses are defined in here and are not null

   }
   messages[msgCount] = new TextMessage(recipient, keyPresses); // Line 54
   msgCount++;
 }
 input.close();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Please post a [mcve], you are leaving out essentially pieces of your code. It looks like `messages` is `static`, if so it is likely wrong to initialize it from the `TextDecoder` constructor; or it indicates that `messages` **should not** be `static`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public TextDecoder() {
    messages = new TextMessage[10];
    msgCount = 0;
  }
```

This is a constructor, which is invoked with `new TextDecoder()`.

You don't invoke this, so `messages` is never initialized. (But you shouldn't be setting static fields in a constructor anyway).

Either make the `readMessagesFromFile` method an instance method (remove the `static`; and create an instance of `TextDecoder` on which to invoke the method); or initialize the state statically.